# Are color combination nodes innately more powerful than plain ones?

Tags: colossatron

Additional nodes are generated in just three colors - red, blue, yellow - but alternate nodes can be created by combining two of the 0-level nodes to create orange, green and purple.

Considering they take twice as many nodes to produce, are these alternate colors more powerful than the primary ones at an equivalent level?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, the secondary colours have increased armour and the weapons are more powerful.  There are a couple of tips in the news ticker that confirm this.

One I can recall reads something like "General Moustache HATES when heavily armoured Green, Orange or Purple POWERCORES are at the front of Colossatron."